# how to tell spring to load resources from custom directory with maven multi-module springboot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I tried to build a maven multi-module web project:

`project A, project B, ...`

**B** dependent on **A**

run project **B**, the console shown than `/hello` were mapped, but `hello.jsp` not found when check `localhost:8080/hello`

here are my questions:

1. how did i use hello.jsp（resources in **A**）while running project B?
2. how to tell spring load resources from directory `src/main/resources/`?

**structure A/B**

```
A/B
|_src
|  |_main
|  |   |_java
|  |   |  |_com.x
|  |   |  |  |_AStarter.java/BStarter.java 
|  |   |  |_com.x.domain
|  |   |  |_com.x.services
|  |   |  |_com.x.web
|  |   |     |_HelloController.java/FooController.java
|  |   |_resources
|  |      |_application.properties
|  |      |_templates
|  |         |_hello.jsp
|  |_test
|      |_java
|      |_resources
|_pom.xml
```

(A)pom.xml were a simple spring-boot like file.
(B)pom.xml similar to (A)pom.xml just add a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>X</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

application.properties:
    spring.view.suffix: .jsp

---

**update**

Starters:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class AStarter extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(AStarter.class);
     }
    public static void run(Class<? extends AStarter> c, String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(c, args);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        run(AStarter.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class BStarter extends AStarter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AStarter.run(BStarter.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controllers:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    private String message = "Hello World";
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("time", new Date());
        model.put("message", this.message);
        return "hello";
    }
}

@Controller
public class FooController {
    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    public String foo(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("foo", "foo!");
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

console:

```
--- {main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/foo],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.x.FooController.foo(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
--- [main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/hello],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.x.web.HelloController.welcome(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
--- [main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
--- [main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
```

**when i check localhoust:8080/hello, error came out**
[image]

Thanks in advance！

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `WEB-INF` with Spring applications; it's always been fragile, and Spring can look in jars on the classpath. Put your files in `src/main/resources/templates` and don't specify any `spring.view.prefix`.

Comment: I did this on both my projects A and B, but still the same problem `Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/hello.jsp` shown on page.

Comment: Then you need to show your controller. This generally means *controller* not found; a view not found would give you a 500. Usually, in Spring, you'd map the controller to `/hello`, not `/hello.jsp` explicitly.

Comment: Did you try loading `/hello`?

Comment: yes i did. i tried `/hello`,`/hello.jsp`,`/foo`, `/foo.jsp`  but got the same error.  does console output necessory?

Comment: Yes, please paste the console lines about mappings.

Comment: updated, sorry to trouble you. how to tell spring load resources from `/resources/templates/`?

Comment: @Teifi Do nothing. Spring Boot will do that by default.

Comment: but am can't visit `hello/foo` if puts them at `/resources/templates/`,if puts them at `/webapp/` just `/foo` could visit, and `/hello` gives me an error page

Answer (score 0):

your pom.xml use `<package>war</package>`? because embbed tomcat not support jsp

for template engine like freemarker, put *.ftl into different fold in classpath, and custom `FreeMarkerConfigurer`

multi-module project like this :

```
  Model-A
    src/main/java
    src/main/resources/templates1/hello.ftl
    pom.xml
  Model-B
    src/main/java
      org.lenic.sof.Application.java
    src/main/resources/templates2/index.ftl
    pom.xml(like Model-A additional dependent on Model-A)
```

and java config like this :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Controller
public class Application {
    private String  message = "Hello World";

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("time", new Date());
        model.put("message", this.message);
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("message", "this is index page");
        return "index";
    }

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        configurer.setTemplateLoaderPaths("classpath:/templates1/", "classpath:/templates2/");
        return configurer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

hello.ftl like this:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>welcome spring-boot!</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        ${message}
    </body>
</html>
```

index.ftl like this:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>welcome spring-boot!</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        ${message}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you resolve this issue?  I'm having the same issue and believe it is caused by the combination of using a maven submodule and the JSP spring view resolver.

Thymleaf tempting engine works fine, and I can move the subproject to it's own project, it works fine (no code or configuration changes required).